# Display Vietnamese and Chinese in MVVM's view (multi-language) by using Resources.resx

Tags: xml, resources, multilingual, resx

I need to display Vietnamese and Chinese in same view, and there are there resx files switch by a combo box. (Resources.resx, Resources.vi-VN.resx, Resources.zh-TW.resx)

My coding tool is VS2017.

There is one value called "cẩu" in my Resources.vi-VN.resx, but it always showed "câ□u" in the view.

I have tried a lot of methods to solve it, but it always failed. 
There are the methods that I have tried before:

1. Write < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"? > on the top of resx file, and value is "cẩu", but it showed "câ□u" on the view.
2. Write < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"? > on the top of resx file, and value is "c&#x1EA9 ;u", but it showed "c&#x1EA9 ;u" on the view.
3. Write < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"? > on the top of resx file, and value is "c@"ẩ"u", but it showed "c@"â□"u" on the view.
4. Write < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1258"? > on the top of resx file, and value is "c@"ẩ"u", but it showed "c@"â□"u" on the view.
5. Write < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1258"? > on the top of resx file, and value is "c&#x1EA9 ;u", but it showed "c&#x1EA9 ;u" on the view.
6. Write < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1258"? > on the top of resx file, and value is "cẩu", but it showed "câ□u" on the view.

This is my first time coding in multi-language, I don't know where's the problem.
I would appreciate every answers!! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Visit this website, I found the answer by myself^ ^ : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5830cb6e-8660-4ef1-be86-ece45fdd28d7/add-vietnamese-string-in-to-resourcesvivnresx-but-it-always-shows-garbled-in-views?forum=csharpgeneral